# Riverpod StateNotifierProvider not refreshing the UI

Tags: flutter, riverpod, objectbox

So I was tired to do the state management with callbacks and I start using Riverpod and it looks awesome. However I have some little troubles to make it work perfectly.

I am making a UI with favorite pictures on the right tab bar and regular pictures on the left.

My problem is that the *favorite pictures tab does not refresh when pictures are removed/added*, my guess is that it would have to do with:

```dart
return favoritesNotifier.when(
      data: (data) => data!.isNotEmpty
          ? FavoritePicturesWidget(data)
          : const Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Empty folder"))),
      loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      error: (e, st) => Center(child: Text(e.toString())),
    );
```

which only load once.

I wonder what I did not setup correctly with Riverpod. (I added the tag objectbox in case it is related to objectbox but I highly doubt so).

Here is my "favoriteProvider":

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import '../../../../objectbox.g.dart';
import '../../../../main.dart';
import '../../../../model/mediaMetadata.dart';


final favoriteProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<FavoriteNotifier, AsyncValue<List<File>?>>(
        (ref) => FavoriteNotifier());

class FavoriteNotifier extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<List<File>?>> {
  //Box<MediaMetadata> imageMetadataBox = objectbox.store.box<MediaMetadata>();

  FavoriteNotifier() : super(const AsyncLoading()) {
    getFavorites();
  }

  void getFavorites() async {
    state = AsyncValue.data(await listChildrenFiles());
  }

  Future<List<File>?> listChildrenFiles() async {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("retrieving favorite albums & pictures");
    }
    Box<MediaMetadata> mediaMetadataBox = objectbox.store.box<MediaMetadata>();
    // mediaMetadataBox.removeAll();
    List<MediaMetadata> imageMetaDataList = mediaMetadataBox.getAll();
    print("length of favorite items: ${imageMetaDataList.length}");

    List<File>? files = imageMetaDataList
        .map((imageMetadata) => ...

    print("number of files: ");
    print(files.length);

    return files;
  }
}
```

The MediaMetadata class:

```dart
import 'package:objectbox/objectbox.dart';

@Entity()
class MediaMetadata {
  MediaMetadata(
      this.myId,  {this.id = 0});


  final String myId;

  @Id()
  int id;
}
```

getFavoriteFilesAPI.dart (relevant parts)

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    ref.read(favoriteProvider);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final favoritesNotifier = ref.watch(favoriteProvider);

 return favoritesNotifier.when(
      data: (data) => data!.isNotEmpty
          ? FavoritePicturesWidget(data) // will load the relevant Pictures widget
          : const Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Empty folder"))),
      loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      error: (e, st) => Center(child: Text(e.toString())),
    );
}
```

and the image widget (long press add it as favorite):

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final qBuilder =
        imageMetadataBox.query(MediaMetadata_.myId.equals(widget.myId));
    final query = qBuilder.build();
    var results = query.find();

    bool isFavorite = results.isNotEmpty;

    return FutureBuilder<universal_io.File>(
        future: getImageFileAsync,
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<universal_io.File> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.hasData) {
            MediaMetadata mediaMetadata;
            if (isFavorite == true) {
              mediaMetadata = query.find().first;
            } else {
              mediaMetadata = MediaMetadata(widget.myId);
            }

            return GestureDetector(
                onLongPress: () => {
                      if (isFavorite == false)
                        {
                          print("adding to favorite ${mediaMetadata.id}"),
                          imageMetadataBox.put(mediaMetadata),
                        }
                      else
                        {
                          print("removing from favorite ${mediaMetadata.id}"),
                          imageMetadataBox.remove(mediaMetadata.id),
                        },

                      setState(() => isFavorite = !isFavorite),

                    },
```

Many thanks in advance I have spent the whole day yesterday, I feel close to the solution but would really appreciate any input.

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: could you send me to the related doc or code snippet for a Future/Async provider? Oh found it: https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/combining_requests

Comment: is ConsumerStatefulWidget deprecated as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your provider has no idea about the removal of item from the list. To solve the issue:

Create a method in the state notifier

```
removeFromFav(item) {
 // update the db from here
 // update the state after removing the item
  state = // updated items
}
```

Call this method from the widget to remove it.

```
ref.read(provider.notifier).removeFromFav(item)
```

Comment: ok this is working slightly better but two problems: 1/ if I remove one favorite, the UI will instantly update BUT if item A, B and C are favorite and B is removed, it will show A and B (instead of A and C), while still understanding that we are in presence of A and C. in my codesnippet FavoritePicturesWidget is a gridviewbuilder.  2/ the UI from left tab is not refreshed (there is a fav icon showing up) when the favorite is removed or added from the right tabbar.

Comment: You need keys in your listview items.  WIthout that, identical items are indistinguishable.  See https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html for details.

Comment: Thanks, I already had keys in my listview items, somehow the issue disappeared while coding and switching to hook riverpod

Comment: I will create a new question because I changed way too many things, taking into account the different comments and @Samuel Robert 's answer